# Is it possible to intercept phone calls in an android application?

Tags: android

I am researching whether it is possible to receive an incoming mobile phone call  and intercept the call within an application so that before we accept the call we can start to play some music in the background such that the caller listen to the music as well.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can ! You will have to create service that listens to incoming call intent and then do what you like.

See this tutorial for more information:

- [How To Handle Incoming Calls in Android](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2012/11/how-to-handle-incoming-calls-in-android.html)